# How to manage multiple Neo4J embedded databases with OGM which can be accessed by more than one process?

Tags: scala, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I would like to manage multiple embedded graph databases with Neo4J. It would be perfect if multiple processes could access the databases concurrently but it seems that a lock file prevents this. The reason to use embedded databases is to avoid the overhead of starting a Bolt/HTTP database with Docker. I want to use a simple setup.

Each embedded database should get its own directory. At one point the user should be able to delete them all.
The problem is that when I create a new embedded database with

```
new Configuration.Builder().uri(path.toUri.toString).build
```

in Scala, it uses the parent directory of my URI to create a lock file and a logs directory.
Therefore, I always have to specify a sub directory like ".../myembeddeddatabase/subdir/".

However, when I close the corresponding session factory, there is always a directory "logs" left with a debugging log.
When I want to delete the directory with

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(storageDir)
```

I will get an exception sometimes and the directory remains due to the sub directory "logs".
How can I wait for the graph database to be shutdown?

Maybe there is a much better way to handle multiple embedded graph databases or do I have to use Bolt/HTTP?
I am considering to store all my graphs in the same database since it seems to be much easier.